# applicationShouldTerminate: not called when application closed on the red X

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks

I am new to OSX development. I have to run some code when the app is about to terminate. `applicationShouldTerminate:` runs when `quit` is selected from the menu or when I press `Cmd Q` but not when I close the app on the red X ball.

How do I do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on osx, per default an app doesnt close when the main window/the last of the app's windows is closed. 
=> An app can run without any windows open.

---

if you want the X to close the app implement the appDelegate method `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` and return YES there!

Comment: You can also implement -windowWillClose: in your windows delegate, if you want to just respond to the window closing.

Comment: THANKS guys, you are fantastic! Just one final question: is applicationShouldTerminate called when the user shuts down or restarts mavericks while the app is running?

Comment: yes if you dont support suddenTermination it should be called.